# RPError: state missing from the response when setting a custom Sketchfab provider with NextAuth v4

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, vercel, next-auth

I'm implementing an OAuth 2.0 flow using [Sketchfab's implicit grant type](https://sketchfab.com/developers/oauth#implement-implicit) via a [custom provider](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider).

It's a simple setup at the moment. Just the signing page at the root of the domain with a button for `signin()`. I'm using Next.js `13.2.4` and Next Auth `4.21.1`.

The `[...nextauth].ts` file is as follows:

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"

const SKETCHFAB_CLIENT_ID = "REDACTED"
const SKETCHFAB_AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://sketchfab.com/oauth2/authorize/"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    {
      id: "sketchfab",
      name: "Sketchfab",
      type: "oauth",
      authorization: {
        url: SKETCHFAB_AUTHORIZE_URL,
        params: {
          scope: "read",
          response_type: "token",
        },
      },
      checks: ["state"],
      clientId: SKETCHFAB_CLIENT_ID,
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
        }
      },
    },
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  },
  debug: true,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

The issue I have is that it throws an error on the final stage, after being kicked back to my app from Sketchfab. I'm hosting with Vercel and this is the server's error log after enabling Next Auth's `debug` option:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error state missing from the response {
  error: RPError: state missing from the response
      at Client.oauthCallback (/var/task/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:524:13)
      at oAuthCallback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:111:29)
      at async Object.callback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:52:11)
      at async AuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:201:28)
      at async NextAuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:19)
      at async /var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:60:32
      at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:9)
      at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:514:9)
      at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:828:35)
      at async Router.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:243:32) {
    name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
    code: undefined
  },
  providerId: 'sketchfab',
  message: 'state missing from the response'
}
```

For the sign in page, Vercel's log is the following:

```
[next-auth][debug][CREATE_STATE] { value: 'Jt_U13aNxYIBiyd-uEQ9P5ECjlPzClMQkACAk-o4WYE', maxAge: 900 }
[next-auth][debug][GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL] {
  url: 'https://sketchfab.com/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=REDACTED&scope=read&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fproduct-kraken.skyixd.com%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fsketchfab&state=Jt_U13aNxYIBiyd-uEQ9P5ECjlPzClMQkACAk-o4WYE',
  cookies: [
    {
      name: '__Secure-next-auth.state',
      value: 'eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..Nj7ht69QuSSUvEvd.rqMbFxOxA99sHnfrGRpn7dkoC91UYe_jFfZcMqqZE4y7wVg-xfpUp5277jp7uzSdGM4YLvD1IrTDk5hyC_1yzF4cNiM-ooMjeeZt4L5L4yaND2mt2aK7oN60Y4AzcPPcAH_axVEuEer29rbTBieBNJIccvWHgPe9tZLTfmOdVhlvMi2p1J4.RorKlTuYxNLsiqxglAzgqg',
      options: [Object]
    }
  ],
  provider: {
    id: 'sketchfab',
    name: 'Sketchfab',
    type: 'oauth',
    authorization: {
      url: 'https://sketchfab.com/oauth2/authorize/',
      params: [Object]
    },
    checks: [ 'state' ],
    clientId: 'REDACTED',
    profile: [Function: profile],
    idToken: false,
    signinUrl: 'REDACTED/api/auth/signin/sketchfab',
    callbackUrl: 'REDACTED/api/auth/callback/sketchfab'
  }
}
```

On my side everhtying seems set correctly, and the `missing state` error seems not correct as domain aside, the error's page URL (called from Sketchfab) is as follows `/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback#access_token=qi7L2kbPCcm68sYsvZ8ZAIiG7h16NS&expires_in=2592000&token_type=Bearer&scope=read&state=S39Mph8lxdZzE2O7AraydXa3mMdCduJfOXkX8F5Fr6g`

So it looks like `state` is indeed present (`&state=S39Mph8lxdZzE2O7AraydXa3mMdCduJfOXkX8F5Fr6g`).

Any suggestions regarding how to dig further are most welcome.

Comment: did you get any fix for this

Comment: I gave up in and switched to PKCE which was fine for me.